# white outline around PNG

Tags: image

I have been stuck with this problem for a while now and cant move on.Im making sticker by applying PNG on object.Everything work just fine only the image have white outlines which i cant get rid off.Pls,any help would be much appreciate.

Comment: If you go into the UV editor for your object, can you try scaling down the UVs so that it fits on the image?

Comment: well i did it by method when I  applyed a subdivision modifyer and shrinkwrap the plane to the model

Comment: Try to change the shading (somewhere I don't remember now) from straight to multiplied.

Comment: please add that as the answer and include screen shots of the settings. Sounds like something other people will get stuck on and will value your answer.

Answer (score 1):

I already figured it out.Changed the PNG options in shader editor from LINEAR to SMART.Outlines are gone –[image]